# Graphing force sensor data routed through HX711?

Tags: arduino-uno, processing-lang

I'm using the code off of the sparkfun website HX711 hookup guide (https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/load-cell-amplifier-hx711-breakout-hookup-guide#arduino-code) to attempt to create a scale.

Currently I have output data of weight in the serial monitor - is there an easy way to then graph this data with regards to time? I've spent an hour fooling around with Processing and googling, but haven't had any luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Include the Time library in your sketch, then print the time and your sensor output as a comma separated list. Your output to the serial monitor can then be written to .csv file using PuTTY, which you will need to download in order to collect data (I used online tutorials to figure out writing to a file with PuTTY). Once in a .csv, you can open the file in Excel to graph the data.